# Border Color in InputBase in React Material

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I need to put a `borderColor` in my `InputBase` in my react material. I tried to do the code below and it still doesn't appear.

I've prepared a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-7di2c?file=/theme/overrides/MuiInputBase.js:0-131)

**CODE**

```
import palette from "../palette";

export default {
  focused: {
    borderColor: palette.primary.main,
    borderWidth: 10
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your import for MuiInputBase is missing from `index.js` file in the code sandbox link. Plus, your css settings for MUIInputBase is incorrect. You should wrap the css object in an input container and set a `border` property before adding borderColor and borderWidth.

```
// Example setting
input {
     "&:focus": {
          border: "1px solid pink"
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I've edited it. But my problem is on the `focus`

Comment: For focus, you can use the "&:focus" css selector in your code just like how you did for button. I updated the answer to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you see the console, there is an issue with the specificity. So make sure to put the style for `focus` inside the `root`

[image]

[working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-input-focus-fix-zszr9?file=/theme/overrides/MuiInputBase.js)

**refactored code**

```js
  root: {
    border: "2px solid blue",
    "&$focused": { //<---- see here
      borderColor: palette.primary.main,
      // borderColor: 'green',
      borderWidth: 10
    }
  }
  // focused: { // this is wrong. Remove this block of code
  //   borderColor: palette.primary.main,
  //   borderWidth: 10
  // }
};
```

**Edit**: Based on comment.....

If you are applying styles normally, then you can simply use `focused` for InputBase in makeStyles.

[Working demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-focus-issue-fixed-jjmm0?file=/demo.js)

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: "2px 18px",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: 400
  },
  focused: { //<---- see here
    backgroundColor: "red",
    borderColor: "2px solid green",
    borderWidth: 10
  },
```

**usage**

```js
<InputBase
        classes={{ root: classes.root, focused: classes.focused }}
        placeholder="Search Google Maps"
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search google maps" }}
      />
```

Comment: Actually. I'm trying to do this on this https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8llxu?file=/demo.js

Comment: What i mean by the border color is like the TextField. I'm trying to apply it in the InputBase